# Keras: Loading minibatches from HDF5 and CSV

Tags: python, neural-network, keras

I have a large dataset, too large to fit into RAM, which is available either as HDF5 or CSV.  How can I feed it into Keras in minibatches?  Also, will this shuffle it for me, or do I need to pre-shuffle the dataset?

(I'm also interested in this when the input is a Numpy recarray; since Keras I believe wants the input to be a ndarray.)

And, if I want to do some lightweight preprocessing in Keras before learning (e.g. apply a few Python functions to the data to change the representation), hcan that be added?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the fit_generator method available with Keras here: https://keras.io/models/sequential/#sequential-model-methods
It fits the model on data generated batch-by-batch by a Python generator  (Where you can write shuffling logic, since generator is under your control).

You may apply call pre-processing within the generator itself.

Hope this helps.